# AndEngine and play video as background

Tags: android, andengine

This is possible to play video as background and show elements of my game over that video? I have a video and I want to this video was my background and my game was played on that video. Can I do that in AndEngine?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. Check out the AumentedReality example in the Andengine examples project:
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/AugmentedRealityExample.java

Comment: Hi, There is no code for playing video in the given link. Can you please provide some more information?